# Not able to set image on ImageView with normal setImageUri and with Picasso - Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to select the image from gallery and send it to other activity. It's working fine in Kitkat but not working in android Nougat. I tried normal setImageUri and Picasso also. Still not able to render the image on Imageview. Please see below code.

1. MainActivity.java - I have one button, on click of button I am calling intent to open gallery.

> ```
> gallery_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onClick(View v) {
>                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
>                     intent.setType("image/");
>                     startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
>                 }
>      });
> ```

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    Log.d("vishal path", selectedImageUri.toString());
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("selectedImg", selectedImagePath);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }



public String getPath(Uri uri) {

        if( uri == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        // this will only work for images selected from gallery
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null ){
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

        return uri.getPath();
    }
```

From above methods, I am able to catch the image path from gallery. I can see on log monitor.

2. ImageActivity

   public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   ImageView mainImg, brushImg, fontImg;
   String imgPath;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

       mainImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSetMain);
       brushImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBrush);
       fontImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageFont);

       mainImg.postInvalidate();;

       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       imgPath = extras.getString("selectedImg");
       Log.d("vishal received path", imgPath);
       // mainImg.setImageURI(null);
       // mainImg.setImageURI(Uri.parse(extras.getString("selectedImg")));
       Picasso.with(ImageActivity.this).load(new File(imgPath)).into(mainImg);

       brushImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(ImageActivity.this, DrawActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("selectedImg", imgPath);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });

       fontImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
       });
   }
   ```

   }
3. activity_image.xml

> ```
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:context="com.example.mobilesolution.imgedit.ImageActivity">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageSetMain"
>         android:layout_width="336dp"
>         android:layout_height="478dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
>         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageBrush"
>         android:layout_width="67dp"
>         android:layout_height="38dp"
>         app:srcCompat="@drawable/brush"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageFont"
>         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
>         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageSetMain"
>         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageFont"
>         android:layout_width="65dp"
>         android:layout_height="37dp"
>         app:srcCompat="@drawable/font"
>         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="83dp"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageSetMain"
>         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
>
> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

And now the main culprit file is here --

I am selecting image in MainActivity.java, by using intent I am passing the image path to next activity called ImageActivity.java.

In ImageActivity.java, I used imageView.setImageUri(uri), not able to see image on device. Same with the picasso.

I have added below dependency for picasso

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Also I have added below permissions to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: are you having problem with Google Photos app?

Comment: @RahulKumar -  Yeah... After opening the image gallery I used to select image from Photo app. I can see image path in log monitor. But facing issue with rendering it on imageview

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    imgPath = extras.getString("selectedImg");
    Log.d("vishal received path", imgPath); these lines work ? I mean is it gives image path or not

Comment: @Opriday- Yes.. It's giving me the path.. "vishal received path: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F119/ORIGINAL/NONE/1972447643"

Comment: Google photos does not give file path of the file, so it has to be done via stream. I have added code when I do the same in `onActivityResult`. You can find the relevance.

Comment: @RahulKumar - Thanks for your reply.. Let me try.. will get back once complete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Intent data = getIntent();
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        if(selectedImage != null && selectedImage.getAuthority() != null) {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567302/1042124
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        }
```

At the end, if `imageBitmap` is not null, load with bitmap into ImageView with Picasso or load it directly.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should check this answer below:

[ACTION_PICK image picker returns diffrent uri formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489915/action-pick-image-picker-returns-diffrent-uri-formats)

maybe different Android OS Version will return different content uri

Comment: can you post this log by Nougat and Kitkat 
Log.d("vishal path", selectedImageUri.toString());

Comment: Kitkat Log:- "vishal received path: content://media/external/images/media/20" 

Nougat Log -: "vishal received path: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F119/ORIGINAL/NONE/1972447643"

Comment: try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527045/choosing-photo-using-new-google-photos-app-is-broken

Answer (score 0):

Try to make bitmap from the file path. then set bitmap to your ImageView.

```
            String ImagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedImg");
            Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath );
            mainImg.setImageBitmap(map);
```